# Show/ hide dynamic combobox

Tags: php, javascript

I have two comboboxes which are generated by queries from mysql.

When user choose value in first combobox i need to display second combobox, but if nothing is choosen second combox should not be displayed.
The code:

```
<?php
echo "<form method= \"post\" name=\"formcombo\" action=''>";
echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Choose main category</option>";
while($cat2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
if($cat2['category_id']==@$category)
{
echo "<option value='$cat2[category_id]'>$cat2[category_name]</option></br>";}
else
{
 echo "<option value='$cat2[category_id]'>$cat2[category_name]</option>";
}
}
 echo "</select></br>";
 echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Choose subcategory</option>";
 while($cat = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
 echo "<option value='$cat[subcat_name]'">$cat[subcat_name]</option>";
   }
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value =\"Submit\">";
echo "</form>";
 ?>
```

I use javascript to generate combobox values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload(form){
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
self.location='main.php?cat=' + val ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need to not show second combobox if nothing is choosen in first one

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with jQuery js library, it is easy.
see this jQuery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectchain

try the demo provided in this page and use the plugin to accomplish.